# What is the difference between "breathe" and "flash"?

Tags: meaning

> The power indicator breathes/flashes when the machine is being
>   charged.

Does "breathe" mean flash softly/smoothly? Dictionaries doesn't define the meaning that fits in this context. What does "breathe" exactly mean in the example sentence above?

Answer (score 2):

It's very uncommon usage, but you sometimes see it being used when talking about computer hardware. The word "breathes" in this sentence is being used to compare the behaviour of the power indicator to a person breathing; i.e. the light is flashing on and off gradually and slowly.

You wouldn't find this meaning for "breathe" in a dictionary because it's fairly informal. I don't think I've ever seen it used like this outside of computer hardware discussions.

Comment: here is [an example of a "breathing" LED](http://static1.squarespace.com/static/52f7e010e4b0b0787ce07b19/t/56afdd8722482e15b61cf1ab/1454366146809/) as an effect on a backlit gaming keyboard.